# Why is there no implementation for 'IQueryable<Foo>.ToLookupAsync(x => x.Bar)'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with asp.net MVC, and I really expected there to be an implementation for an asynchronous ToLookup functionality like this:

```
var myLookup = await IQueryable<Foo>.ToLookupAsync(x => x.Bar);
```

Is there a technical reason for not wanting asynchronicity with regards to a lookup, or has this simply never been implemented? Upon Googling, I did see [a request for it in .Net Core](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/15916).

Comment: Surely this question would have been better asked on the page your provided - since those guys are the ones actually implementing it?

Comment: That page is .NET Core, not the original non-core.NET